# animation through changing the background image of a div

Tags: javascript, html

We are trying to mock an animation by changing the background of a div element through a sequence of images and repeat the cycle. There are four 533x800 8-bit PNG images each about 110KB in size. A JavaScript function is run through `setInterval` and it changes the div background to the next image every 300 milliseconds. I thought this would not be heavy task for the browser but turns out that there is too much lag. Especially on mobile devices. What better way would you suggest to achieve this?
Below is the JS (jquery) function to change background. Thanks

```
function changeBackground() {
    if ( typeof changeBackground.counter == 'undefined' ) {
        changeBackground.counter = 1;
        changeBackground.backObject = $('#body');
    }

    if ( changeBackground.counter == 5 )
        changeBackground.counter = 1;

    changeBackground.backObject.css( 'background-image', "url(graphics/" + changeBackground.counter + ".png)" );
    ++changeBackground.counter;
}
```

Comment: Please post the javascript code you're currently using so it can be analyzed.

Comment: Can't you just make an animated GIF out of these images? This would result in only one image to load and no need for javascript.

Comment: @Paul i don't currently know how to produce GIF but will see that. Do GIFs support transparency?

Comment: One idea would be to have a single compressed image that is a sprite of your animation so the script is simply changing the background position of your sprite.

Comment: @Paul Should this be posted as an answer instead? It's a good one.

Comment: GIF supports transparency, but only in a boolean way (pixel is 100% transparent or not). PNG-24 supports alpha transparency with any values between 0% and 100%. BTW, there are numerous online animated GIF generators which offer the service for free. Shouldn't take more than 5min to get an animated GIF out of one.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Create one large compound background image by placing all four images next to each other. Then load the background and change it's position (so it shows one of the four 'frames') every 300 milliseconds instead of loading a new background every time

Comment: I think a GIF would be better: it could partially load and still function, while you'd have to wait your yours to load at least a quarter of the way.

Comment: so final verdict, i make a gif or i make a sprite? :P

Comment: Depends on how heavy the image is I think. I believe apple used the method I'm suggesting to do their countdown timer for the app store (1.000.000.000 downloads counter)

Comment: @JeroenMoons Well it would be ridiculous to use a GIF there.

Comment: 4 frames of 110 kb makes one sprite of 440kb, which is not that much these days. I'd go with sprite personally because it's easier to create and edit later

Comment: @arxanas you could use ten gifs counting from 0 to 9 with different speeds, but you have a point :)

Comment: GIF results in 960kb. sprite is a little messier.

Comment: I have more such sequences, one is with 22 images 224x254 32-bit each about 13 kb. The cycle is not simple but first ten, then go in reverse back to 1 then 11 to 21 then go in reverse back to 10. So i think sprite is more useful there too

Comment: sprite is smaller then, another reason to go with it. I personally don't think it is messy, this technique works really well for all kinds of background image needs (elements with hover/active/click states etc.) and you have only one file to worry about. No delays in switching background.

Comment: Indeed, you can easily play with display order without having to create new files.

Comment: you're right. Thanks everyone for such quick and generous help

Answer (score 1):

*As proposed by [CalMlynarczyk](https://stackoverflow.com/users/691501/calmlynarczyk), I am posting my comment as an answer.*

You should just make an animated GIF out of these images. This would result in only one image to load and no need for javascript (meaning it also works with javascript disabled).

Regarding transparency, GIF supports it, but only in a boolean way (pixel is 100% transparent or not, whereas PNG-24 supports alpha transparency with any values between 0% and 100%). Also, there are numerous online animated GIF generators which offer the service for free. Shouldn't take more than 5min to get an animated GIF out of one.

With only so many images, it is also fairly easy to create the GIF with GIMP (open source, free). And if you save the working file, you can easily reorder the image sequence or change time between frames.

Comment: A little more help please... i have a sequence of 32-bit pngs that need boolean transparency but since I don't know what to do about it i had to retain the whole alpha channel, otherwise the images would even be fine with 8 bit color depth. So the question is, I would like these images to have 8 bit color depth and boolean transparency. How can this be done?

Comment: Load the images into something like GIMP and save as GIF. This automatically creates a 8-bit color palette (since GIF only supports up to 256 colors).

Comment: thanks :) I made the gifs and put them in. One gif is 530KB with 300 ms delay between frames (4 frames) and one is 130KB with 50 ms between frames (40 frames). There are only two GIFs. PC browsers have no problem displaying them but android browsers are crying :'(